# How do I remove a MassAction from the Product Grid using Observers in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, events

I want to remove the "Delete" mass action from the Products grid. I am trying to do this from my observer. Here is my observer class

```
class NameSpace_Module_Model_Observer {

public function isAddProductDeletePermitted($observer) {
    $block = $observer->getBlock();
    if( $block !== null ) {
        if( $block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Grid) {
            $block->getMassactionBlock()->removeItem('delete');
            // echo "DELETE";
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

And here is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

    . . .

    <global>

        . . .

        <events>
            <adminhtml_block_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <is_add_product_form_permitted>
                        <class>Dotlocal_AdvProductGrid_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>isAddProductDeletePermitted</method>
                    </is_add_product_form_permitted>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_block_html_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

I cannot seem to get this to work. I am pretty sure this doesn't work because I am trying to removing it before it is added. Then what event should I be observing?

Comment: Are you sure about `instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Grid` I think the block in the product page is more likely to be of type `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in my comment, the type you are checking is wrong.

Two possible solutions.

You get the right grid, which is `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` and your code become

```
class Some_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function isAddProductDeletePermitted ( $observer )
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock ();
        if ( $block !== null ) {
            if ( $block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid ) {
                $block->getMassactionBlock()->removeItem('delete');
                // echo "DELETE";
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Or you can also do it on every admin grid (with the generic block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`) and then verify, with the handle of the page, if you are on the product listing page or not.

Like this :

```
class Some_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function isAddProductDeletePermitted ( $observer )
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock ();
        $layout_handle = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles();
        if ( $block !== null && $layout_handle[3] == 'adminhtml_catalog_product_index') {
            if ( $block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid ) {
                $block->getMassactionBlock()->removeItem('delete');
                // echo "DELETE";
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this to attach an acl for deleting products. I can now turn a this dropdown item on and off. Is there any other hang ups or "loop holes" I am missing in my logic?

Comment: Maybe you could try to narrow your event so you do not get so many useless events being caught by your Observer. I did not tried but you can try with `adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction` -> `./app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php:311:        Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction', array('block' => $this));`

Answer (score 0):

Since `_prepareMassaction()` method dispatch event `adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction` you should be able to do

```
<events>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction>
        <observers>
            <is_add_product_form_permitted>
                <class>Dotlocal_AdvProductGrid_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>isAddProductDeletePermitted</method>
            </is_add_product_form_permitted>
        </observers>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction>
</events>
```

Then in your observer

```
class Some_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function isAddProductDeletePermitted ( $observer )
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock ();

        if ($block) {
             $block->getMassactionBlock()->removeItem('delete');  
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

See app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php

Answer (score 0):

```
class Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid {

    /**
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid|Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid|void
     */
    public function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        parent::_prepareMassaction();

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->removeItem('cancel_order');
    }
}
```